# Google Glassware release Checklist

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api

we are finalizing our glassware and i was going through the launch checklist as from [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/distributing/checklist).

In the first part of the document we are asked to provide a set of icons. I can guess that i need to put them in the root of the glassware but:

1. is there any naming convention i need to follow?
2. is there a config file i need to fill this names with?

Comment: What spacing/margins are you using around your pixel source image artwork? Looks like the art should not go to the border. Also for the 640x360 icon, are you using an 'iconified' look or is a photo acceptable here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found the solution.
It was almost trivial, all this data are required when you submit the app via the proper form.